# A workflow engine that actions in a flow can be binding dynamicly

Tags: java, workflow, business-process-management

I am attempting to build a distributed system.

The system is composed of composite services.

In order to balance the load of the system, I will decompose the composite service and send each service to different server and run parallelly.

So I want to find a workflow engine which can bind the webservice address for each action on the runtime.

Is there any available workflow engine?

Answer (score 1):

A workflow engine ( or api) has nothing to do with load balancing the calls to the service( if it does so,it  increases the coupling , is not it? ) , a workflow should just execute a service or a facade service ,the facade service will call the individual services, which are load balanced by the server. I hope it make sense.

Bottom line is, It is your infrastructure team which will create the infrastructure for the load balancing and which service goes to which node, and it is your job who calls this services, if composite service is what is needed, then you may choose a facade service which delegates calls to the individual services. Your workflow system should not try to load balance.